# Can you only lower the breakdown threshold voltage of solid insulators once with high-voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, high-voltage, insulation

For example, insulator Z has a threshold voltage of 1000V. After exposing insulator Z to more than 1000V, its breakdown threshold voltage is now 800V. Can I lower the threshold voltage further with high-voltage or can I only lower the breakdown threshold voltage once?

Here's a quote from the [source material](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-2/nonlinear-conduction/) I'm reading that has me asking this question.

> Many solid insulating materials exhibit similar resistance properties:
>   extremely high resistance to electron flow below some critical
>   threshold voltage, then a much lower resistance at voltages beyond
>   that threshold. Once a solid insulating material has been compromised
>   by high-voltage breakdown, as it is called, it often does not return
>   to its former insulating state, unlike most gases. It may insulate
>   once again at low voltages, but its breakdown threshold voltage will
>   have been decreased to some lower level, which may allow breakdown to
>   occur more easily in the future. This is a common mode of failure in
>   high-voltage wiring: insulation damage due to breakdown. Such failures
>   may be detected through the use of special resistance meters employing
>   high voltage (1000 volts or more).

I'm mainly interested in the possibility of lowering the voltage threshold further by repeated high-voltage breakdowns as described above. I understand that different insulating materials have different properties, however I don't know enough to be anymore specific. Maybe you can provide me with an example if that would help?

Comment: Is your described behavior coming from some real datasheet, or are you just making it up as a hypothetical?

Comment: In any case, it doesn't sound like an approach I'd want any product designed around.

Comment: Manifacturers don't specify the "death spiral" characteristics, they specify how to avoid it...

Comment: It's a hypothetical, and I made up the values. I want to know if there exists limitations to this as I already asked. For example, if there are no limitations, then I could breakdown the voltage for rubber gloves to the point where they wouldn't protect me from electric charges.

Comment: What your asking for is called "destructive testing", and ties in with @MarkU's answer. This is normally done in isolated (arcing/explosion proof) labs designed to find the point where a product or device fails. Answers to your question would be full of opinions or much too long, and would be copies of existing test trials. This is not something we do here at EE.SE. Be more specific in terms of materials and maybe we can point you to a path to follow for answers.

Comment: I edited my question. I made my question more black and white.

Comment: Please note that when someone who has "sparky" as part of their name tells you stuff about breakdown voltage you should listen ;). Right @Sparky256 ?

Comment: @placeholder. That has been my nickname since 5th grade when I was making AM radios and my own stun guns. From 1995 to 2011 I worked at a plant designing, programing and running a 5GW (32KV@ 150KA) lightning generator. I really do miss that job...

Comment: After exposing insulator Z to >1000V, you should check the rating for repeated overload, then consider changing to a higher rated insulator. Eventually, you'll hit catastrophic breakdown and have failure (during surge or during normal operation), even if the nominal operating potential of Z is say, 200V, in the application.

Comment: It sounds like you are wondering if you can use dielectric failure as a method to tailor the breakdown voltage of a cable system. This doesn't seem to me like  a fruitful idea. The effects of the breakdown probably depend on the specific type of insulation, how long the breakdown lasts, and how much current flowed through the damaged area. The wire may also be damaged by highly energetic breakdown events.

Comment: @BryanO'Neil My reading of that is that when it is broken, you can't rely on it any more, and you don't know it what ways you can't rely on it any more. You would have to characterize the performance of a particular material by experiment.

Comment: Okay, hopefully I can test this out for myself in the future. I'll remain hopeful that someone can answer my question so I don't have to.

Comment: The other aspect to remember is that the insulation will only break down in the region of high stress. The rest of it will be unaffected. On a slightly related topic, I know that in some industries 2-layer rubber gloves are the standard. The inner layer is yellow and the outer is red. The gloves are inflated for inspection and if any yellow is visible through surface wear or cracks then the gloves are discarded.

Comment: The degradation of the insulating characteristics progressively tends towards catastrofic failure modes.  As the insulator degenerates it will conduct more current and fail on some permanent way.  Statistically there may be a trend towards reduction in insulating capacity along some curve function as a result of over voltage events but it will not be predictable.  Some security tools are intended to withstand a single overload condition like rigging.